# My question is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion

Could you please stop marking my question as an exact duplicate?  [Current capacity of laser drilled micro vias](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312665/current-capacity-of-laser-drilled-micro-vias)

A micro via structure is not the same as a barrel plated via structure and that is exactly why I asked the question.  Please stop linking it to the generic via question.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Are you saying the structures are the same?

Comment: No, it means that someone (not me) didn't like the question, rep doesn't matter in the meta anyway. It would probably be better to ask this question in the moderator chat room.

Comment: No, this is exactly where these questions are supposed to be asked.

Comment: Only this is not a question. It's a demand - and as such leaves little scope for the community to express an opinion.

Comment: You aren't really supposed to express any opinion either. I suppose this is more of a [support] request than a [discussion].

Comment: The question you link to isn't closed, so there is apparently no problem here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question that is in question by the OP is not closed.

Comment: @laptop2d its status changing doesn't make this off topic. OP isn't a mind reader, it got reopened 3 hours after they posted, which was 27 hours after it was closed.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is taken care of, no one needs to be bothered by this question anymore

Answer (score 2):

Multiple users voted to close as duplicate. This is a typical bandwagon effect that happens sometimes.

A few hours after you posted this, the question was reopened by 2 regular users and a mod vote.

This sometimes happens and you took the correct measures to address this. An edit of your post explaining the difference (prior to the 5 close votes) and asking on meta.